# In chrome browser Bootstrap Datetimepicker work after I inspect the web page only. Normally it does't work

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Once I *inspect the web page working fine* but I opened in Incognito it doesn't work.

```
jQuery('#pickupdate').datetimepicker({

    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    ignoreReadonly: true,
     minDate: new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)

});


jQuery('#dropoffdate').datetimepicker({

    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    minDate: new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0),
    useCurrent: false,

});
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: I posted my code above can you please check it

Comment: In all browsers? What browser have you tested? Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: Shouldn't matter but you have a trailing comma in your 2nd datetimepicker options. `useCurrent: false,`

Comment: No errors in console. And it happens on chrome browser only.

Comment: Try using moment.js as it is natively supported in that picker? `minDate: new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)` -> `minDate: moment().startOf('day')`

Comment: I removed the comma but same output.. :(

Comment: Are you using a document ready?

Comment: Please wait sir, I will try moment().startOf('day') and i also tried document ready function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153021/discussion-between-venkatesh-srikanth-and-fjoe).

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a [Document Ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)?

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#pickupdate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        ignoreReadonly: true,
        minDate: new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)
    });

    jQuery('#dropoffdate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        ignoreReadonly: true,
        minDate: new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0),
        useCurrent: false
    });
});
```